# Problema com condiçao no While em C++

Tags: while, c++14

Olá, estou estudando a partir do livro "PROGRAMMING Principles and Pratice Using C++" do Bjarne. Estou tentando fazer Drill número 1 do capitulo quatro. O exercício diz para fazer um programa que consiste em um while-loop que leia e imprima dois inteiros e pare quando for escrito |, porem, quando escrevo | (ou qualquer outra coisa que não seja um número) o programa fica em um loop infinito. Se alguém puder me explicar o que tem de errado no meu código, já tentei ler no livro sobre conversões de int pra char e vice e versa e mesmo assim o erro persiste, deem uma olhada.

```
#include <...\Projects\std_lib_facilities.h>

int main()
{
    //drill's
    //1 - inicio

    /*escrever um programa que consiste em um while-loop que leia dois int e termine quando 
é escrito |  */

    int n=0, n1=0;

    cout << "Write a int. To stop the program hit |";

    while (n != '|' || n1 != '|' )
    {
        cin >> n >> n1;

        system("cls");

        cout << n << " " << n1 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem alguma coisa que diz que as variáveis precisam ser `int`? Dá para colocar o enunciado do exercício? Ou é só isso aí?

Comment: /*escrever um programa que consiste em um while-loop que leia dois int e termine quando 
é escrito |  */ é este, irei comentar abaixo o original do livro.

Comment: Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two int and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered.

Comment: Estou tentando entender a intenção de fazer isto para dar uma resposta.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado enquanto isso farei uma revisão no Cap se eu achar algo posto aqui @bigown

Comment: Isso foi perguntado no SO, mas parece que o exercício é outro :)

Comment: É o gomiero passou o link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o post no SO (em inglês):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349857/how-to-handle-wrong-data-type-input

> A razão para o programa entrar em um looping infinito é por causa de
>   um *flag* (sinalizador) de entrada inválida do dispositivo
>   **std::cin**.
>
> O que precisa ser feito é limpar a flag e descartar a entrada inválida
>   do buffer de entrada.

Após a correção, o código fica assim:

```
while (n != '|' || n1 != '|')
{
    // limpa a flag
    std::cin.clear(); 

    // Descarta a entrada
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::cin >> n >> n1;

    system("cls");

    std::cout << n << " " << n1 << "\n";
}
```

A entrada "errada" está ocorrendo por causa da leitura de um (tipo) caracter "**|** " em uma variável do tipo numérica `n` ou `n1`.

Para mais detalhes (em inglês):

[C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istream-and-ignore)

Outras possibilidades para corrigir:

- ler o conteúdo **|** para uma variável tipo `char`
- ler cada valor para um buffer do tipo `string` e depois converter para inteiro com a função [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

**Atualização:**

Após aplicar a segunda sugestão de correção, o looping fica assim:

```
int n = 0, n1 = 0;

std::string buffer;

std::cout << "Write a int. To stop the program hit |";
while (n != '|' || n1 != '|')
{
    // Lê a primeira entrada
    std::cin >> buffer;

    // Se for um "|", sai do looping
    if (buffer == "|")
        break;
    // Converte para inteiro
    n = std::stoi(buffer);

    // Lê a segunda entrada
    std::cin >> buffer;

    // Se for um "|", sai do looping
    if (buffer == "|")
        break;

    // Converte para inteiro
    n1 = std::stoi(buffer);

    // Limpa a fila std::cin
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    // std::cin >> n >> n1;

    //system("cls");

    std::cout << n << " " << n1 << "\n";
}
```

Mesmo com essa correção, o código acima ainda está sujeito a outros erros.

Abaixo, segue uma sugestão de leitura para entender melhor como funciona o sistema de entrada e saída de dados em C++:

[Entrada e saída de dados](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C%2B%2B/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_de_dados)

Comment: Muito obrigado gomiero irei testar e ler o FAQ para ficar mais adentro.

Comment: bom o looping infinito resolveu porem para min não mudo nada é como se a condiçao do while não existise agora pois escrever | ele simplismente descarta o | e pede para ler outro digito no lugar ao invez de terminar o while, eu ja tentei ler o conteudo | em um char irei testar fazendo a conversao de string para int agora que foi a unica opçao que nao tentei até agora. obrgado mais uma vez pela ajuda

Comment: meu professor comentou o seguinte "Se vc não mudar o valor de uma das variáveis dentro do loop. Ela sempre vai ter o valo | e portanto o laço vai ser repetido...."

Comment: converti para string depois pra int vlw ajudou bastante ainda mais os links muito obrigado.

Comment: perfeito exatamente essa logica que usei obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: viu eu sempre venho aqui dar uma olhada nessa explicação ela resolve altas coisas ainda XD tenho que tomar mais cuidado nessas coisas obrigado novamente cara