# Erro logico no for

Tags: loop, lógica, c++14

Oi pessoal eu estou tentando fazer um loop controlado para o meu programa, até agora esta correndo normal só que somente na primeira rodada, na segunda repetição ele pula a primeira passada do for e inicia na segunda posiçao se alguem quiser ver meu codigo:

```
void Intro_Game();
void Login_Entrace();
bool Ask_PlayAgain();
string User_Login(string);
constexpr int WORLD_LENGHT = 5;

int main()
{
    bool PlayAgain_Count = false;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        Intro_Game();
        Login_Entrace();
        PlayAgain_Count = Ask_PlayAgain();
    } while (PlayAgain_Count);

    return 0;
}

void Intro_Game()//Intro Game
{
    cout << "Welcome to Bulls & Cow\n";
    cout << "Can you guess the " << WORLD_LENGHT << " isogram I'm think of?\n\n";
}
//entrace of data process fase
void Login_Entrace()
{
    string x[5];
    int j = 1;

    //begin fase
    for (int i = 0; i < WORLD_LENGHT; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter with Guess " << j << ": ";
        x[i] = User_Login(x[i]);
        system("cls");
        j++;
    }

    j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < WORLD_LENGHT; i++)
    {
        ++j;

        cout << "Guess " << j << "  name is: " << x[i] << "\n\n";
    }//end fase
}

bool Ask_PlayAgain()
{
    string resp;

    cout << "Do wanna play again?\n";
    cin >> resp;

    if (resp[0] == 'Y' || resp[0] == 'y')
        return true;

    if (resp[0] == 'N' || resp[0] == 'n')
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "You say no. =(\n";
        return false;
    }

    if(resp[0] != 'N' || resp[0] != 'n' && resp[0] != 'Y' || resp[0] != 'y')
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Wrong awnser please try again\n";
        return Ask_PlayAgain();
    }
}

//Read user login name
string User_Login(string Guess)
{
    getline(cin, Guess);

    return Guess;
}
```

> Atualização

Pessoal irei colocar essa foto espero que exemplifique a minha questão.
[image: Resolução do erro]

> Atualização com resposta (explicação do Gomiero na resposta postada abaixo)

[ShareCode](https://codeshare.io/zrRs7)

Comment: Deixa ver se entendi...na primeira execução ele roda os dois for certinho, só que na segunda ele pula o primeiro e e executa só o segundo?, se nao for isso, tenta esclarecer melhor.

Comment: Quase ... assim o primeiro for na primeira vez ele lê certo os 5 guess e imprime certinho, ai chama o askplay_again... se eu respondo Yes ele inicia o do novamente mas ele já inicia pedindo para ler o segundo guess... no caso ele pula até a intro_game e já pede o guess 2

Comment: Espero que não tenha ficado complexo

Comment: Se o output do console não for muito grande, acho que ajudará a esclarecer o problema. Adiciona ele na sua pergunta e mostra em que instante o programa começou a 'errar'...

Comment: No caso a variavél J não esta passando o valor correto....é isso?

Comment: coloquei uma foto para melhorar a explicaçao @DungaCardoso

Comment: Entendi agora. que estranho, ele incrementa as váriaveis..porém a variavel i e J do segundo for não é incrementada.

Comment: então eu ja li e li novamente e nada não consegui pensar em fazer de outra forma por que para esse tipo de coisa nem necessita de tanto mas se alguem tiver alguma ideia do que está acontecendo, eu não conheço lugar melhor pra perguntar

Comment: Eu nao trabalho com essa línguagem...mais ja tentou tirar aquele count++, que se é uma váriavel não vi declaração, ou entao tentar fazer um reset nas variaveis depois dele em vez de antes.

Comment: Então toda vez q entra na função de login ele setá j=0 e quando entra no for ele seta i=0 nos dois for

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35694/discussion-between-dunga-cardoso-and-leonardo-v-de-gasperin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi corretamente o problema, mas provavelmente o erro está na linha:

`cin >> resp;`

Dentro da função `Ask_PlayAgain()`.

Na leitura da entrada padrão, está "sobrando" um caracter após a leitura e, por isso, na segunda execução do `getline(cin, Guess);` ele já lê esse caracter "a mais".

Se o problema for este, a solução é limpar a entrada logo após a leitura da variável `resp` (conforme esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111121/problema-com-condi%C3%A7ao-no-while-em-c)):

```
...
cin >> resp;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
...
```

Para o `numeric_limits` funcionar, é necessário incluir: `#include <limits>`.

Comment: Noooossa nao duvido na verdade ate me esclareceu as ideias vou testar la e ja volto

Comment: iiiihuuuuu obrigado @Gomiero pela ajuda a té mesmo pela claresa da explicação eu mechi bastante nessa função para descobrir se era nela o erro coloquei até no final dela um return NULL; para ver se resolvia, tentei usar o fflush(stdin) da stdio.h e nada. Muito Obrigado novamente